# How to structure Tests for Vue Components to have a good coverage?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I was wondering in general how to properly test Vue Components to cover almost everything, to confidently tell a customer that it works and it will not fail unless something big happened.

In my case I am using Jest as the test framework. It comes with coverage reports that follow the Istanbul pattern.

However what I am uncertain about is how to structure the tests to minimize the overhead, maximize the test speed (or atleast not create bottlenecks), maximize extendability  and maximize the test coverage.

Furthermore I am also uncertain with Integration-tests
where you handle the interaction of multiple components, mixins, vuex-store and other js-files.

Should they have a separate and dedicated file or would put everything into one file?

So my question is, how to put everything together as I can write good single tests in each but finding a good structure to help me and my co-workers with the coverage and low overhead is a bit difficult for me.

Here is an example of a structure I recently developed to test a certain Vue-component with jest & vue-test-utils:

```
//some imports
describe("Test Vue-Component X", () => {

  let wrapper = null; 
  beforeAll(async () => {            //could also be beforeEach. (Depends on the component I guess
    localVue = createLocalVue();
    localVue.use(Vuex);
    vuetify = new Vuetify();
    wrapper = mount(somecomponent, {
      mocks: {
        $t: (key) => translations["messages"]["EN"][key],
      },
      localVue,
      store,
      vuetify,
    });
  });

  describe("Initial State test", () => {
    /**
     * GIVEN 
     * WHEN 
     * THEN 
     */
    test("checks if Component X exists", () => {
      expect(wrapper.vm.$options.name).toBe("X");
      expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
    });
    describe("Created", () => {});
    describe("Mounted", () => {});
    //Does it generally make sense to go throw each lifecycle-hook or is it rather test specific?
  });
  describe("computed Properties: ", () => {
    describe("Property Y", () => {
      /**
       * GIVEN  
       * WHEN 
       * THEN 
       */
      test("Test some Expected Outcome", () => {
      });
      /**
       * GIVEN  
       * WHEN 
       * THEN 
       */
      test("Test Error Cases", () => {});
    });
    describe("Proterty Z", () => {});
  });
  describe("methods ", () => {
    describe("Method 1", () => {
      /**
       * GIVEN 
       * WHEN 
       * THEN 
       */
      test("Test some expected outcome given a specific imput ", () => {});
      /**
       * GIVEN 
       * WHEN 
       * THEN 
       */
      test("Test Error-case 1", () => {});
    });
    describe("Method 2 ", () => {});
    describe("Method 3... ", () => {});
  });
  describe("Watch ", () => {
    describe("Watcher A", () => {});
  }); 
  describe("Interaction Vuex store? ",()=>{
      //e.g. test if the store yields some stuff that is breaking the UI 
  });  
  describe("Interaction with template? ",()=>{
      // would go in the direction of ui-test similar to the selenium tests
  });  
  describe("Dedicated Bug Area? ",()=>{
      //all tests made because of bug reports
  }); 
  describe("Events or Interaction with other components? ",()=>{
      //all tests made because of bug reports
  }); 
});
```

The part where I am uncertain about are marked with a "?".

Maybe it would be great if you could link me to a test that was tests a complex Vue-Component with a 100% coverage (covering unit and integration-tests) in a middle to big project.